# Couchdb trying to group by array value

Tags: javascript, object, underscore.js, couchdb

I have a problem transforming my array.
Below is a example input:

```
            {
          "_id": "beaconlog_888ff29df356c803_Amsterda",
          "_rev": "5152-3c6e5f47d6860179cf80b9bca3efba4b",
          "beacon_identifier": "Amsterdam",
          "beacon": "office",
          "in_region": true
        }
```

I created a view in couchdb with this map function:

```
        function (doc) {
          if(doc.beacon) {
            emit([doc.beacon_identifier, doc.beacon, doc.in_region],1);

          }
        }
```

for reduce i use _count on group_level 3

This is my current output:

Output:

```
{
            "rows": [{
                "key": ["Amsterdam", "office", false],
                "value": 2
            }, {
                "key": ["Amsterdam", "office", true],
                "value": 1
            }, {
                "key": ["Rotterdam", "office", false],
                "value": 1
            }]
        }
```

And this is what I want to achieve as final resultset:

```
{
    "Amsterdam": {
        "inactive": 2,
        "active": 1
    },
    "Rotterdam": {
        "inactive": 1
    }
}
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Why `"false": 2` for `Amsterdam`???

Comment: @Tushar It's from `"value"`.

Comment: You should probably add your input array too so we can understand the transformation better.

Comment: I agree, the input array would help to make it easier understand the problem and figure out the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both solutions are in plain javascript.

The first solution features your original data set and iterates over the elements and get the wanted object with adding properties to a property and add some values if given.

```js
var array = [{
        "_id": "beaconlog_888ff29df356c803_Amsterda",
        "_rev": "5152-3c6e5f47d6860179cf80b9bca3efba4b",
        "beacon_identifier": "Amsterdam",
        "beacon": "office",
        "in_region": true
    }],
    result = {};

array.forEach(function (a) {
    var TYPE = ['inactive', 'active'];
    result[a.beacon_identifier] = result[a.beacon_identifier] || {};
    result[a.beacon_identifier][TYPE[+a.in_region]] = (result[a.beacon_identifier][TYPE[+a.in_region]] || 0) + 1;
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

The second solution takes your above mentioned *output* and builds an object with your wanted specification.

```js
var object = { "rows": [{ "key": ["Amsterdam", "office", false], "value": 2 }, { "key": ["Amsterdam", "office", true], "value": 1 }, { "key": ["Rotterdam", "office", false], "value": 1 }] },
    result = {};

object.rows.forEach(function (a) {
    var TYPE = ['inactive', 'active'];
    result[a.key[0]] = result[a.key[0]] || {};
    result[a.key[0]][TYPE[+a.key[2]]] = a.value;
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Hi Nina, thank you it's working great with your solution!

Answer (score -1):

```
o.rows.reduce(function(result, input) {
  var bool = input.key[2];
  var city = input.key[0];
  result[city] = result[city] || {};
  result[city][bool] = input.value;
  return result;
}, {});
```